# Indexing when using the l3doc class

Tags: indexing, l3doc

I am using the `l3doc` class for a write-up the document needs to index both macros as well as normal indices, i.e; cases with normal words not commands.

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\def\thepage{\Alph{part}-\arabic{page}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part {First Part}
\section{first section}
\subsection{first subsection}
Just a test
\cmd{\chapter}
\index{Book Class>chapter}
\index{chapter design}
\cs{l_tmpa_tl}
\cs{tl_new:N}

\newpage

\part{Second Part}
\cs{l_tmpa_seq}
\cs{seq_new:N}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The l3doc is using Roman letters to force the sorting of l3 functions and variables and this causes an issue with normal indices (see image).

[image]

**I have added a bounty in order to attract more attention
I am simply looking for a macro say `Index[options]` that can have  a  similar functionality as `index`, when using the `l3doc` class. This to be used for non-command entries. Using `\NewDocElement` I have macros for everything else, except this. So `\Index[module={Gods}]{Greece>Zeus}` would print a three level entry and be sorted properly. I know I can use `NewDocElement` and define custom commands for this, but I want to give this flexibility to the author, as there are so many variations.**

Comment: `\def\@ywrindex#1{%
  \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
  {\string\indexentry{#1}{\thepage}}%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\def\yindex{\@bsphack\begingroup \@sanitize\@ywrindex}
\def\@yindex#1{\endgroup\@esphack}` (from `latex.ltx`)?

Comment: @cfr  Thanks. I had something similar, which fixes some of the issues,i.e., indexed in roman rather than ttfamily and the levels. Remaining problem is to trick hypdoc and l3doc to provide the right link to the page. I think the solution is to also redefine the hypdoc/hyperref  `hdpindex`  to another name |yhdpindex{usage}}{MMMMI-66} and also to find out where the target is inserted and to insert in your code.

Comment: @cfr  It needs a patch to `hyperref`  to add a   `\@ywrindex` then `hypdoc` and possibly `doc v3` and `l3doc`. It is like the scramble for Africa in the 19th century.    l3doc in my opinion sucked the flexibility out of the indexing, by trying to sort the modules in groups. makeindex would do this on its own. Putting `l_tmpa_tl` under the group `tl` is also misleading and not worth the inflexibility introduced.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to use `l3doc` in that case?

Comment: @cfr  I hooked into l3doc macros  to capture code in macrocode and color them.  I am too much into it at the moment to backtrack.

Comment: By the way, I don't think you need to load `hyperref`. `l3doc` already loads `hypdoc`, doesn't it? I don't really understand the 19th century analogy, but I assume that's just me. I don't get the impression, though, that `l3doc` is designed for flexibility. It's intended to format a particular set of documentation in a standard way.

Comment: @cfr   Yes `doc` v3 loads `hypdoc` which loads `hyperref`. The primary purpose of these is to document latex source code.

Comment: Yes, but the primary purpose of `l3doc` is to document the LaTeX 3 project's documentation of LaTeX 3. So `doc` is designed for flexibility, but `l3doc` is not.